# Vim-Plug: Can't install plugins. Invalid plug directory

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vim-plug

I'm new to vim. The problem happens when I type `:PlugInstall` I get:

```
[vim-plug] Invalid plug directory: /Users/joqsan/.vim/plugged. Try to call plug#begin with a valid directory
```

---

This is how I installed `vim-plug`:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload/ $ cd ~/.vim/autoload/
$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

In `.vimrc` I have:

```
set number

if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.plug"))
source ~/.vimrc.plug
endif
```

In `~/.vimrc.plug`:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
call plug#end()
```

But when I reload `vim` and type `:PlugInstall`, I get:

```
[vim-plug] Invalid plug directory: /Users/joqsan/.vim/plugged. Try to call plug#begin with a valid directory
```

If I type `:scriptnames` I get this:

```
1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
2: ~/.vimrc
3: ~/.vimrc.plug
4: ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim
5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
7: /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim
8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
13: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
14: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
15: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
16: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
17: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
18: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
19: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
20: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
21: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
22: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

Since I don't see `~/.vim/plugged`, I try to create the directory:

```sh
$ mkdir ~/.vim/plugged
```

But I get:

```sh
net120:~ joqsan$ mkdir ~/.vim/plugged
mkdir: /Users/joqsan/.vim/plugged: File exists
net120:~ joqsan$
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit 1**: Directory structure of `~/.vim` and `~/.vim/autoload`

```sh
net120:~ joqsan$ ls -la ~/.vim/autoload
total 256
drwxr-x---  3 root  staff     96 Mar 30 12:33 .
drwxr-x---  4 root  staff    128 Mar 30 13:14 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  74434 Mar 30 13:45 plug.vim

Joqsans-MacBook-Air:~ joqsan$ ls -al ~/.vim
total 0
drwxr-x---   4 root    staff   128 Mar 30 13:14 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 66 joqsan  staff  2112 Mar 30 17:38 ..
drwxr-x---   3 root    staff    96 Mar 30 12:33 autoload
-rw-r--r--   1 root    staff     0 Mar 30 13:14 plugged`
```

---

**Edit 2:**

[image]

---

**Edit 3:**

On OS X, the primary group is always `staff`, so I think this is ok. I didn't create the directory `~/.vim`. I installed vim with homebrew (I mean, I did nothing manually).

After doing what you recommended I got this:

```
Joqsans-MacBook-Air:~ joqsan$ sudo chown joqsan:staff ~/.vim
Joqsans-MacBook-Air:~ joqsan$ ls -al ~/.vim
total 0
drwxr-x---   4 joqsan  staff   128 Mar 30 23:08 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 67 joqsan  staff  2144 Mar 31 04:28 ..
drwxr-x---   3 root    staff    96 Mar 30 12:33 autoload
drwxr-xr-x   2 root    staff    64 Mar 30 23:08 plugged
```

With respect to the previous prompt (in **Edit 1** above) now the first two directories are owned by `joqsan`, but I still get the error when typing `:PlugInstall`. Maybe that is because `autoload` and `plugged` are still owned by `root`?

---

**Edit 4:**

```
Joqsans-MacBook-Air:~ joqsan$ sudo chown -R joqsan: ~/.vim
Joqsans-MacBook-Air:~ joqsan$ ls -al ~/.vim
total 0
drwxr-x---   4 joqsan  staff   128 Mar 30 23:08 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 67 joqsan  staff  2144 Mar 31 13:11 ..
drwxr-x---   3 joqsan  staff    96 Mar 30 12:33 autoload
drwxr-xr-x   2 joqsan  staff    64 Mar 30 23:08 plugged
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you run `$ mkdir /Users/joqsan/.vim/plugged` in your shell?
If you get a “Permission denied” error message, try to change the owner of the `~/.vim/` directory by running `$  chown joqsan:joqsan /Users/joqsan/.vim`.

Comment: Relevant code: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/d1c19a6fa934d90718c18e40acbec0ad7014e931/plug.vim#L984

Comment: @klaus I did that and it seems that everything is ok. I mean, no error is reported (above posted what appears).

Comment: @user938271 Above posted what appear when using `mkdir`: `mkdir: /Users/joqsan/.vim/plugged: File exists`

Comment: @klaus *You should report your problem in the issue tracker of vim-plug*. Do I do that in github?

Comment: It seems you have a file where vim-plug wants to create a directory. Make a backup in case it contains important data, and move it: `$ mv /Users/joqsan/.vim/plugged /Users/joqsan/.vim/plugged.bak`.
Then try again to create the directory: `$ mkdir /Users/joqsan/.vim/plugged`.

Comment: @klaus Sorry. I confused with the other `ls -al` command that I tried. Edited to post above, putting what I got with `ls -al ~/.vim` at the end.

Comment: @klaus I did this (with `sudo`, otherwise I get a Permission Denied). When typing `:PlugInstall` the error is not shown anymore and execution goes ahead, but the installation of the plugins fails. I've added I picture above with the new problem ): . As I googled, the error reads: `fatal: could not create work tree...`. I thought the problem was just something with the plugin that I had (`Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'`) so I added the line `Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'` just to check, but with both happens the same.

Comment: @Jazz, I commented on the answer below, check that please. Also, I'm removing my comments here as not to clutter the space.

Answer (score 1):

As posted in the [comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19376/vim-plug-cant-install-plugins-invalid-plug-directory#comment33660_19376):

> You have a file where vim-plug wants to create a directory

Create a back up and get it out of the way:

```
mv ~/.vim/plugged ~/.vim/plugged.bak
```

Then try again.

Also make sure you own the directory:

```
sudo chown $USER: ~/.vim
```

The vim directory can become owned by root if you use `sudo vim`—the correct technique is to set the `EDITOR`or `VISUAL` variable and invoke `sudoedit`.

Comment: When I do that I got: `mv: rename /Users/joqsan/.vim/plugged to /Users/joqsan/.vim/plugged.bak: Permission denied. To handle this do I have to do it with `sudo` or try to change the owner as suggested in the comments?

Comment: You ought to change the owner there... if you don’t have permissions there’s something even wonkier going

Comment: In your output of `ls` I see that you're working on two separate machines from 2 different users. First of all, don't use `sudo` for anything related to plugins, it shouldn't require that. And also from output of `ls` command I see that the whole `~/.vim` folder is chowned by root user of staff group. Did you create it with `sudo`? If so, just chown it back to your own user with `sudo chown username:username ~/.vim`. You'd need sudo here to take back what's yours. Unless, this is actually your work computer. Maybe that's why there is a usergroup named `staff`?!

Comment: @klaus mac’s come with a user group named staff by default. Its weird, yes, but normal

Comment: @klaus I did what you suggested, but the problem still persists (I edited my post above with what I got in the Terminal now). Maybe I have to apply `chown` with `autoload` and `plugged`...

Comment: @Jazz why is everything owned by root???

Comment: @Jazz, sorry, I thought doing a chown on the .vim would do the trick. But you need to do it recursively. I suggest you do a little research on how to do it. In linux, I can do `sudo chown -R klaus:klaus ~/.vim` and it should make the whole thing mine.

Comment: @klaus OPs on a mac, which is unix-based. Should work the same

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I'm concerned over the sudo thing. That's why I suggested a little research. But it should solve the problem, isn't it?

Comment: @klaus I think the problem is fixed. The 4rd Edit above shows the result. After a little research I ended up doing `sudo chown -R joqsan: ~/.vim`, to avoid the `illegal group name` message. This means that in some steps of the vim-plug installation I did something with `sudo`, which changed the ownerships, right?

Comment: @Jazz, yes. But I am not 100% sure that you won't have to go through this again when you create another file/directory under `~/.vim`, but that's for another time. I think your `:PlugInstall` problem is fixed, right?

Comment: @klaus Yep, it's fixed. Thank you both for taking the time to help me with this. I'll be more careful with that `sudo` thing.